# Show JSON in Opera

Tags: browser, json, opera

I'm looking for an easy way to show a JSON-like response from our server in Opera. It should be easy to read, e.g. in a tree-like fashion.

If I use Dragonfly I only get to see the response wrapped in an HTML-body element.

Is there a plug-in out there? What do you use for this? I'm using Opera 11.50.

I know I could use Firefox and its plug-ins, but it would be much more useful in Opera.

Comment: Chrome has a nice plugin for this (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) as does firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/). Perhaps better suited for webapps.SE?

Comment: So I had me thinking whether or not this question fits here. So I posted it on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Well, I got my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check [addons.opera.com](http://addons.opera.com)? There is one called [JSONViewer](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/jsonviewer/1.2/?display=en).

Comment: No, I hadn't. Google doesn't seem to know about it neither... Thanks, that seems to be what I wanted to have.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Source" extension for Opera, it shows and highlights a lot of formats (incl. JSON).

Comment: This also sounds interesting, but I usually use Dragonfly and UltraEdit for this.

Comment: That's not the same. This extension allows you to beautify and display code in browser, it isn't debugger or editor. Only one more useful utility.